# Surface Plotting

Tags: plotting, visualization

I want to Plot a surface using `ListPlot3D`. The Data used to feed the Plot is generated from measurments. The Problem is, sometimes the measurments generates x number of points for one row.
Another time the measurments produces only y number of points.
For better understanding, one dot in the sketch represents one measuring point.

[image: Sketch of the measured Surface]

When trying to plot the surface, `ListPlot3D` treats every row as a single surface and so the result looks like this.

[image: Result when using ListPlot3D]

I created a little example that hopefully show's the Error.

```
Data = {{{0.1, 5, 0.9}, {0.2, 5, 0.87}, {0.3, 5, 0.89 }, {0.4, 5, 
    0.82}, {0.5, 5, 0.85}}, {{0.5/3, 10, 0.85}, {2 0.5/3, 10 , 
    0.88}, {3 0.5/3, 10 , 0.86}}, {{0.1, 15, 0.9}, {0.2, 15, 
    0.87}, {0.3, 15, 0.89 }, {0.4, 15, 0.82}, {0.5, 15, 0.85}}};

MyError = ListPlot3D[Table[Data[[i]], {i, 3}], DataRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Data = {{{0.1, 5, 0.9}, {0.2, 5, 0.87}, {0.3, 5, 0.89}, {0.4, 5, 0.82}, {0.5, 
     5, 0.85}}, {{0.5/3, 10, 0.85}, {2 0.5/3, 10, 0.88}, {3 0.5/3, 10, 
     0.86}}, {{0.1, 15, 0.9}, {0.2, 15, 0.87}, {0.3, 15, 0.89}, {0.4, 15, 
     0.82}, {0.5, 15, 0.85}}};
```

Your `Data` is structured as three lists of points and you asked for it to be plotted as such.

Note that that result can also be obtained with the simpler

```
ListPlot3D[Data, DataRange -> All]
```

To obtain a single plot you want to `Flatten` your `Data` to a single list of points.

```
data2 = Data // Flatten[#, 1] &;

Show[
 ListPlot3D[data2], Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[data2]}]]
```

[image]